# Redirect hwnd GDI calls to system memory bitmap?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, activex, gdi

I have a 3rd party ActiveX control I want to render within other presentation technologies (Direct3D and WPF).  To do this, I need the ActiveX to render to a system memory bitmap instead of the screen.  I know there is a way to do this, but not sure where to start.  I'm not afraid of doing any native method hooking, but I'm not sure where to start.  I was thinking BeginPaint(...) might be the hot ticket...

Has anyone done this or seen examples/samples floating around?

BTW, I do not want to do a WM_PRINT type solution.  I'd rather this code be reactive, than proactive and forcing the hwnd to repaint.

EDIT:

Both answers were right in my case, so I gave each a +1.  I wish to have a lower level solution to be more flexible, but this is good enough at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your site support the [IOleInPlaceSiteWindowless](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682300(VS.85).aspx) interface?

Windowless support in ActiveX controls is unfortunately optional. If the 3rd party interface does support it then you can render the control using IViewObject::Draw onto whatever surface you want.

Answer (score 3):

You're best bet is to see if the ActiveX object supports [IViewObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680763(VS.85).aspx) and call the [Draw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688655(VS.85).aspx) method to get it to render into your DC.

If the object doesn't support standard OLE interfaces, you're going to have a very difficult time getting this to work.  You'll have to resort to doing evil things like re-writing the DLL's import table to redirect BitBlt(), etc.  I've done this sort of thing.  I don't recommend it.

Your next problem will be how to correctly map input events.